# SwiftUI Form Icons

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-form

Sorry if this is a really stupid question and maybe offtopic, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

I'm trying to do a simple settings section for my app and would like to add icons to my elements so users can easily understand what does each setting does. To achieve that, I used Horizontal Stacks (`HStack`) with an Image and a Label (`Text`).

This somehow does the trick but I'd like to know if there's a cleaner way to do this.
I'd also like to know how to adjust the separator between cells to stop on the label, and not continue until the end of the element.

As I'm not really good at explaining, here you have two images:

**This is what I got**
[image]

**I'd like to have something similar to this**
[image]

**My code**:

**SettingsView.swift**

```
struct SettingsView: View {

    @State var age: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .singleLine

        UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()

        return NavigationView {

            Form {

                Section {
                    Picker(selection: .constant(1), label: HStack {

                        Image(systemName: "paintbrush")
                            .font(Font.system(size: 25, weight: .light))

                        Text("Editor Theme")
                    }) {
                        Text("Ayu Mirage").tag(1)
                        Text("Ayu Light").tag(2)
                    }
                    Stepper(value: self.$age,
                            in: 18...100,
                            label: {
                                HStack {

                                    Image(systemName: "rectangle.stack")
                                        .font(Font.system(size: 25, weight: .light))

                                    Text("Number of snippets: \(self.age)")
                                }
                    })

                    NavigationLink(destination: NotificationSettingsView()) {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "app.badge")
                                .font(Font.system(size: 25, weight: .light))

                            Text("Notifications")
                        }
                    }

                }

                Section {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                        Text("Mercury v1.0")
                            .font(.headline)
                        Text("Designed with ❤️ by amodrono")
                            .font(.footnote)
                    }.padding(.vertical, 5)
                }

            }

            .navigationBarTitle("Hello")
            .environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .regular)
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Settings"), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: (
                Button(action: {
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(named: "adaptiveColor")!))
                }
            ))

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the separator from the tableview and add your own divider.

Something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
        return NavigationView { 
            Form { 
                Section { 
                    RowView(iconName:"rectangle.stack", text:"Some text")
                    RowView(iconName:"paintbrush", text:"Some other text", showDivider: false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RowView: View {
    var iconName: String
    var text: String
    var showDivider = true
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
            Image(systemName: iconName)
            VStack(alignment: .leading) { 
            Text(text)
                if showDivider { 
                    Divider()
                } else {
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

do you mean like this? (if yes, just switch darkmode on ;))

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
public struct DarkView<Content> : View where Content : View {
    var darkContent: Content
    var on: Bool
    public init(_ on: Bool, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.darkContent = content()
        self.on = on
    }

    public var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if on {
                Spacer()
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                darkContent.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity).background(Color.black).colorScheme(.dark)
            } else {
                darkContent
            }
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension View {
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    public func darkModeFix(_ on: Bool = true) -> DarkView<Self> {
        DarkView(on) {
            self
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var age: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .singleLine

        UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()

        return NavigationView {

            Form {

                Section {
                    Picker(selection: .constant(1), label: HStack {

                        Image(systemName: "paintbrush")
                            .font(Font.system(size: 25, weight: .light))

                        Text("Editor Theme")
                    }) {
                        Text("Ayu Mirage").tag(1)
                        Text("Ayu Light").tag(2)
                    }
                    Stepper(value: self.$age,
                            in: 18...100,
                            label: {
                                HStack {

                                    Image(systemName: "rectangle.stack")
                                        .font(Font.system(size: 25, weight: .light))

                                    Text("Number of snippets: \(self.age)")
                                }
                    })

//                    NavigationLink(destination: NotificationSettingsView()) {
//                        HStack {
//                            Image(systemName: "app.badge")
//                                .font(Font.system(size: 25, weight: .light))
//
//                            Text("Notifications")
//                        }
//                    }

                }

                Section {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                        Text("Mercury v1.0")
                            .font(.headline)
                        Text("Designed with ❤️ by amodrono")
                            .font(.footnote)
                    }.padding(.vertical, 5)
                }

            }

            .navigationBarTitle("Hello")
            .environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .regular)
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Settings"), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: (
                Button(action: {
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .imageScale(.large)
                    //    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(named: "adaptiveColor")!))
                }
            ))

        }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
        .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
        .darkModeFix()
    }
}
```

[image]